# Alt + Access key not working on CMFCMenuBar For none english languages

Tags: mfc, keyboard-shortcuts, menubar

I'm using the CMFCMenuBar class to display my main frame menu, the menu contains access keys like "&File" when the user press Alt + F It will open the File menu, but this is not working for me it shows a line under the access key and after pressing Alt the first menu item in the main menu highlight and I can navigate using the arrows key (Up, Down, Right, Left) but not the access keys

[image]

As we see the menu items has line under the access key but it is not working how to trace it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was fixed after some search I traced the processing of the key

I reached this MFC code

```
BOOL CMFCToolBar::TranslateChar(UINT nChar)
{
    if (!CKeyboardManager::IsKeyPrintable(nChar))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    UINT nUpperChar = CKeyboardManager::TranslateCharToUpper(nChar);//this line guided me

    CMFCToolBarButton* pButton = NULL;
    if (!m_AccelKeys.Lookup(nUpperChar, pButton))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ASSERT_VALID(pButton);

    // Save animation type and disable animation:
    CMFCPopupMenu::ANIMATION_TYPE animType = CMFCPopupMenu::GetAnimationType();
    CMFCPopupMenu::SetAnimationType(CMFCPopupMenu::NO_ANIMATION);

    BOOL bRes = DropDownMenu(pButton);

    // Restore animation:
    CMFCPopupMenu::SetAnimationType(animType);

    if (bRes)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return ProcessCommand(pButton);
}
```

I traced this line CKeyboardManager::TranslateCharToUpper(nChar);
it start with

```
UINT __stdcall CKeyboardManager::TranslateCharToUpper(const UINT nChar)
{
    if (nChar < VK_NUMPAD0 || nChar > VK_NUMPAD9 ||
        (::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU) & 0x8000))
    {
        if (!CMFCToolBar::m_bExtCharTranslation)
        {
```

I searched for the CMFCToolBar::m_bExtCharTranslation, I got that bug report http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/525656/hot-key-is-not-working-on-russian-language-for-applications-which-uses-mfc-feature-pack

### The Solution

---

we needed the following addition in the startup of the application I put it in the method ***CMainFrame::OnCreate***

```
CMFCToolBar::m_bExtCharTranslation = TRUE;//it is FALSE by default
```